# How-to configure Spring 4.0.5 to use an @ExceptionHandler instead of an ExceptionResolver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have added an @ExceptionHandler method on a specific controller.

```
@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.Not_FOUND)
public @ResponseBody doSomeThing(NullPointerException e) {...}
```

Problem is : I have also an custom

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver
```

defined as a @Component in my Rest Application (Legacy).

Now the @ExceptionHandler in my specific controller never gets called. I need to support both Exception Handling strategies.

How can I configure spring 4.0.5 so that my @ExceptionHandler in my Controller gets called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DispatcherServlet` by default will load and register all `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementations within the `ApplicationContext` to help with processing Exceptions from your `Controllers`. You'll notice that `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` class implements `Ordered`. Most `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementations extend this class and `DispatcherServlet` uses this to order the list of `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementations when it comes to handling Exceptions thrown by your `Controllers`.

As you might suspect, the processing of `@ExceptionHandler` annotations on your `Controllers` is also handled by a `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementation. To be precise: `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`

What I would suggest is happening in your case is that the sort of `HandlerExceptionResolver` by the `DispatcherServlet` is causing your implementation to be invoked before the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` meaning that your `@ExceptionHandler` annotations are effectively ignored.

To counteract this, we need to do two things:

1. Directly register the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` as a bean within your `ApplicationContext`
2. Set the `Order` value of this bean to be greater than that of your custom `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementation

This will mean that when it comes to handling `Exceptions` for your `Controllers`, Spring will first see if the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` can handle the Exception, and if not, fall back to your custom `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementation.

As an example of the setting the order on a `HandlerExceptionResolver` (assuming you're using XML configuration somewhere):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" p:order="1" />
```

You may also want to take a look at list of `HandlerExceptionResolver` implementations registered with `DispatcherServlet` by default and decide upon the order that most suits your application.

Comment: Since spring 3.1 use ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver please.