# Multiple Spring Exception Resolvers - Defer resolution

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a situation where I support a framework that needs to resolve a specific exception, but only if that exception has a specific message code (internal exception).  I have added a custom HandlerExceptionResolver to handle this specific exception but am curious how to "defer" the handling of this exception to later resolvers when I don't find a matching message code.

The API calls for returning ModelAndView and the documentation infers to return null for default processing.  Is there anything I can return to indicate to invoke other resolvers?  I could theoretically implement the BeanPostProcessor and capture any other resolvers, but that seems hacky...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to just throw the exception which will be handled later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning null is the right thing to do.

If you look at `DispatcherServlet`, you'll see that it does the following when it comes to handling an `Exception` from your `Controllers`:

```
// Check registered HandlerExceptionResolvers...
ModelAndView exMv = null;

for (HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver : this.handlerExceptionResolvers) {
    exMv = handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
    if (exMv != null) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Essentially this means that it will try all registered `HandlerExceptionResolver` instances within the `ApplicationContext` until it finds one that can handle the Exception. By returning null, you are simply saying that `DispatcherServlet` should try the next one in the chain.

I assume that it makes sense for your `HandlerExceptionResolver` to be called before the other default ones added by Spring. If that is the case, see my other post on how to order your `HandlerExceptionResolver` instances [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092118/how-to-configure-spring-4-0-5-to-use-an-exceptionhandler-instead-of-an-exceptio).

Comment: Thank you, and yes I am definitely ordering mine to the highest priority.  Thank you for the feedback and suggestion.